# How to get values from Dtype object in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with this column structure:

```
<pre>
In [179]: df.dtypes
Out[179]: 
layer         int32
row           int32
column        int32
segment       int32
reach         int32
Qin         float64
Qaquifer    float64
Qout        float64
Qovr        float64
Qprecip     float64
Qet         float64
stage       float64
depth       float64
width       float64
Cond        float64
Qwt         float64
deltaUZ     float64
GWh         float64
kstpkper     object
k             int32
i             int32
j             int32
dtype: object

In [180]: df.kstpkper
Out[180]: 
0          (0, 0)
1          (0, 0)
2          (0, 0)
3          (0, 0)
4          (0, 0)
5          (0, 0)
            ...
18207    (35, 10)
18208    (35, 10)
18209    (35, 10)
18210    (35, 10)
18211    (35, 10)
18212    (35, 10)
Name: kstpkper, dtype: object
</pre>
```

I would like to split kstpkper variable in two and add them to my dataframe.  Is it possible?

How can I call each element in kstpkper variable?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

An efficient way to do it would be to construct a new dataframe from `kstpkper` values and `join` it with the existing dataframe

Consider the test dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=[1, 2, 3],
        kstpkper=[(0, 0), (1, 2), (5, 11)],
        C=np.ones(3)
    ))

print(df)

   A    C kstpkper
0  1  1.0   (0, 0)
1  2  1.0   (1, 2)
2  3  1.0  (5, 11)
```

Then we construct and join like this

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.kstpkper.tolist(), df.index, ['kstpkper1', 'kstpkper2']))

   A    C kstpkper  kstpkper1  kstpkper2
0  1  1.0   (0, 0)          0          0
1  2  1.0   (1, 2)          1          2
2  3  1.0  (5, 11)          5         11
```

Comment: This answer my question. Thanks.

Comment: @Hugo remember to accept this answer if it does indeed solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension is one way:

```
df['kstpkper1'] = [x[0] for x in df.kstpkper.values]
df['kstpkper2'] = [x[1] for x in df.kstpkper.values]
```